# Get the approved and unapproved agreements as separately by POSTGRES on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Consider the below schema for **User**, **Agreement** and **TaxiBooking** tables:

**Users:**

```
id - integer.  
name - string.  
email - string.  
agreement_id - integer
```

**Agreement:**

```
id - integer.  
approved - boolean.  
expired_at - date.
```

**TaxiBooking:**

```
id - integer.  
booked_time - datetime.  
boarding_point - string.  
destination_point - string.  
client_name - string.  
user_id - integer
```

An **Agreement** can be left approved or unapproved.

**Agreements** have default validity period like 6 Months and after 6 Months period the agreement will get expired. expired_at will store the date of expiry of the agreement.

Here the Rails relationship of **User** with **Agreement** and **User** with **TaxiBooking** are below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agreements
  has_many :taxi_bookings
end
```

Rails Relation of **Agreement** with **User** is

```
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Rails Relation of **TaxiBooking** with **User** is

```
class TaxiBooking < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Here I need query the users data who do not have unexpired and approved agreements and have taxi_bookings with future booked_time with below values:

1. Nearest taxi booking time (in future) of the users from the TaxiBookings table.
2. Last approved and expired agreement id with expiry date.
3. Yes/No - i.e. if user have any unapproved and not expired agreements then return **Yes** else **No**.

I tried the below query.

```
User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN agreements ON users.id = agreements.user_id AND agreements.approved = ?  ORDER BY users.id, agreements.expired_at ASC', true).select('DISTINCT ON (users.id) users.id, agreements.expired_at AS expired_at')
```

But I can't able to get all the values in single query.

Can we able to get the all above values from single query? Please give some efficient way to get values for above.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While its good that you have provided your models and a vague outline of what it is that you want to accomplish you need to show us what you have actually attempted to do to solve the issue. This is a Q&A site and not a free code writing service.

Comment: @max I tried the query - User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN agreements ON users.id = agreements.user_id AND agreements.approved = ?  ORDER BY users.id, agreements.expired_at ASC', true).select('DISTINCT ON (users.id) users.id, agreements.expired_at AS expired_at'). But can't able to get all the values in single query. Is there any efficient way to query the all values?